# Real-valued function vanishing on lattice points

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I'm looking for a smooth, real-valued function $f$ that vanishes at the lengths of vectors in the hex lattice $A_2$. More specifically, let's say $f\in{C^{\infty}}(\mathbb{R})$ and nonzero except at the points $1,\sqrt{3},2,\sqrt{7},3,\sqrt{12},\sqrt{13},4,\sqrt{19},...$
Basically, I'm wondering if there is a natural generalization (or means of construction) to the function $x \mapsto \sin(\pi x)$ which vanishes on the integer lattice.

We could, or course, ask a more general question by replacing $A_2$ with an arbitrary lattice $\Lambda$.

$\textit{Background}$: One basic way to approach problems of constructing functions with known/forced zeros is to interpret the real-valued $f$ as a restriction of a complex-valued function and make use of Hadamard's factorization theorem:

$\underline{Thm}$: If $f$ is entire and of growth order $\rho$ and $k$ is the integer such that $k \leq \rho < k+1$, then if $a_1,a_2,...$ are the non-zero zeros of $f$, then

$$f(z) = e^{p(z)}z^m \prod_{n \geq 1} E_k(z/a_n)$$

where $p$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq k$, $m$ is the order of the zero of $f$ at $z=0$, and the $E_k$ are the Weierstrass canonical factors

$$E_k(z) = (1-z)e^{z+z^2/z+ \cdots + z^k/k}$$

In this case, our desired function might look like

$$f(z) = e^{p(z)}z(1-z)(1-z/\sqrt{3})(1-z/2) \cdots$$

I am wondering what better methods exist out there. Thanks!

Comment: What is exactly the problem you are trying to solve, without any extra ideas of what you are considering. Is it only smooth function? It is much simpler to interpolate with smooth functions than holomorphic/meromorphic functions (which are the constructions that you are trying to imitate).

Comment: You might want to look into [elliptic functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_function) although they are complex valued and have poles if nonzero. And here is how [hexagonal lattices are related to parallelogram tilings](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_lattice).

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a nice/simple/canonical way to construct a function with the above specifications